# Jsession id error in the script using jmeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Hi i have 5 transaction in the script

1.Login

2.Click functionality

3.Search

4.Create

5.Logout

I have checked with browser only ONE JSession id passing login to logout transaction.

but in my script login to click functionality transaction passing one jsession id and remaining transaction (3.Search, 4.Create, 5.Logout) are passing (new) another Jsession id.

I have correlated Jsession id and passed the all request inside the header i have done beanshell post processor and added http cookie manager but it takes new Jsession id when it comes to search transaction.

P.S JSession ids are stored in the response header in set - cookie area and also click functionality transaction generates new Jsession id

But In browser only one jsession id created for whole iteration

Could you please tell me about how to fix this issue..

Answer (score 0):

If it comes in [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header and being sent via [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header - the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) should handle this automatically.

If it doesn't - you can increase debug logging verbosity for it by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

and check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for the related entries.

It might be the case the cookie is broken somehow (expired, doesn't match the current URL, etc.), if this is the case you can set [cookie policy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpclient/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/http/client/params/CookiePolicy.html) to something more relaxed, i.e. `netscape`

[image]

and/or add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)

Comment: I have tried this solution. It is not working.is there any other way to fix this issue